# Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a Spring Boot Application, however, I cannot get the first page to load. It seems (based on many similar questions asked) that there can be various reasons for this error, however, none of which seem to resolve the issue causing this particular error. I feel like it can't hurt having a few insights into this issue on SO?

Currently the error is:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Controller Methods

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
  @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

        return "registration";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.save(userForm);

        securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null)
            model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        return "welcome";
    }
```

Webconfig File

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Application.properties

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/arearatingdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
spring.messages.basename=validation
```

My Directory is set up as follows:

[image: Screenshot of directory]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please update
`spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false` in application.properties

Answer (score 0):

i figured out similar problem by just adding
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false in application.properties